# gem install rails "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, rubygems

Getting my local environment setup for Ruby on Rails.

So I have rails installed in my .rbenv file, and when I type `which rails`, that's confirmed.

`where rails` shows the `/Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims` folder where rails is *multiple times*, like 15 times currently, then one single entry for `usr/bin/rails`.

However, if you run `rails --version`, you get this:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

If you run `gem install rails`, you get this:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

But if you go back and run `where rails` again, you'll get even more entries for the `/Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims` directory, indicating that it's incrementing each time.

Tried to add an env variable my ~/.zshrc as per some guidance online, as so: `export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"`

When I save and source it, I get a different error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/<username>/.gem/gems/racc-1.7.3/ext/racc/cparse
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20240118-44186-1bplyzo.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/<username>/.gem/gems/racc-1.7.3/ext/racc/cparse
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/<username>/.gem/gems/racc-1.7.3/ext/racc/cparse
make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin22/ruby/config.h', needed by `cparse.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/<username>/.gem/gems/racc-1.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/addie/.gem/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/racc-1.7.3/gem_make.out
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: How did you install ruby? It seems like your whole setup might be broken.

Comment: Do you have the OS X command line tools installed?

Comment: Engineersmnsky i don't recall exactly how, i believe through brew?       Beartech Not sure which ones you mean. How would I go about checking?

Answer (score 0):

try sudo gem install rails and add your password, I faced this issue while trying gem install cocoapods